# Renew command begin figure?

Tags: macros, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro for figure position?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/macro-for-figure-position)

Is it possible to make change that changes all instances of

```
\begin{figure}
```

into

```
\begin{figure}[h]
```

?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  Yes, see [Macro for figure position?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/macro-for-figure-position/11342#11342). Please tell if you need further help, otherwise I close this question as duplicate of the linked one to keep the place tidy. Thanks.

Comment: I should add that it's not a good idea: if a figure can't be placed "here", it and all following figures will appear at the end of the chapter. Floating figures has been used from the beginning of typography.

Comment: I agree with @egreg. You might want to use a non-floating replacement instead for this cases. See [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float).

Comment: See also: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned).

Comment: What is difference between floating and non-floating? Can you provide me link to some manual with explanation?

Comment: See the explanation here: [Floats, figures and captions](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/floats_figures_captions) by Andrew Roberts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{ht}
```

I use `ht` instead of `h` because LaTeX doesn't allow only a `h` placement for a float. `h` will be automatically converted to `ht` and make a warning.