# Latex figure, default option [h]?

Tags: floats, positioning

It seems that the figures in my document are positioned at the top of the page by default. Is it possible to change that default behaviour to [h]? (without adding [h] to all the figures)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: Be aware that `h` alone is not possible and will always be substituted by `ht`. If you want to prevent your figures from floating completely, just don't use floating environments.

Comment: @Johannes_B Frank's opus tells of many things, but not how to set the defualt:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just noticed :-D `\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{h}` for figures. Again, not a good idea i think.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/macro-for-figure-position/11342#11342

Comment: Never set the default to h (or use `[h]` explicitly you always want to include at least `p` and probably `t` so \renewcommand{\fps@figure}{htp}